# login based on user roles

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

problem with my assignment....

I also need to make users login based on whether their role (usertype) is 'reader' or 'client' to be redirected to the proper welcome page. Plus i want to use my custom model (User's username & password) for login credentials. I have read the django docs custom auth but i still don't know i will implement it into my project.

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length='10')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    username = models.CharField(max_length='50', unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length='50')
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length='12')
    city = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    country = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('adminwelcome')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('invalid')
```

template

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block title %}Log In - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Sorry, that is not a valid username or password</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action = "auth_view" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" />
        <br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    <p>Not Registered? <a href="register">Create Account </a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please split those two questions into different posts..

Answer (score -1):

What i did was that when my User model form is being saved, it should get the username, password and email and create a user in the Django auth User table using this line of code

```
User.objects._create_user(request.POST['username'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'],False,False)
```

This is the full code in the views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            User.objects._create_user(request.POST['username'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'],False,False)
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect('register_success')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['forms'] = RegisterForm()
    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

Then for the login based on roles, I had to make the user a staff from the admin end by setting the `'is_staff' = true`. After that, all i had to do was pass the `'is_staff==True'` in the auth_view request during login authentication. A bit dirty but it does the trick. Any further optimization is appreciated. Cheers.

Views.py

```
def auth_view(request):
    username1 = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password1 = request.POST.get('password', '')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)

    #check if user has been set to staff (reader), redirect to reader welcome
    if user is not None and user.is_staff==True:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('readerwelcome')

    #check if user is not staff(client), redirect to client welcome
    elif user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('clientwelcome')

    #if login details not found, return error page
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('invalid')
```